# Rails fields_for not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, field

I am trying to use `fields_for` and create a nested form, however only one text field shows up, blank.  I have 3 `crewmember` records.

`crewmember` model:

```
class Crewmember < ActiveRecord::Base
belongs_to :production
belongs_to :callsheet

validates :firstname, presence: true
validates :email, presence: true

def name
    "#{firstname} #{lastname}"
end

end
```

`callsheet` model

```
class Callsheet < ActiveRecord::Base
attr_accessible :crewmembers_params
has_many :castmembers
has_many :crewmembers

accepts_nested_attributes_for :crewmembers
end
```

`callsheets` controller

```
class CallsheetsController < ApplicationController
    def index
        @callsheets = Callsheet.all
        @departments = Department.where(production_id: current_user.default_working_production_id)
    end

    def show
        @callsheet = Callsheet.find(params[:id])
    end

    def new
        @callsheet = Callsheet.new
        @departments = Department.where(production_id: current_user.default_working_production_id)
    end

    def edit
        @callsheet = Callsheet.find(params[:id])
    end

    def create
        @callsheet = Callsheet.new(callsheets_params)
        @Callsheet.production_id = current_user.default_working_production_id


        if @callsheets.save
            redirect_to callsheet_path
        else
            render 'new'
        end
    end

    def update
        @callsheet = Callsheet.find(params[:id])

        if @callsheet.update(callsheets_params)
            redirect_to callsheet_path, :notice => "callsheets successfully updated."
        else
            render 'edit', :notice => "callsheets not updated."
        end
    end

    def destroy
        @callsheet = Callsheet.find(params[:id])
        @callsheet.destroy

        redirect_to callsheets_path
    end

    private
        def callsheets_params
            params.require(:callsheet).permit(:crewmembers_params [:id, :firstname])

        end
end
```

form for new callsheet:

```
<%= form_for @callsheet do |f| %>
  <% if @callsheet.errors.any? %>
    <div id="error_explanation"  class="alert alert-danger">
      <strong>
      <%= pluralize(@callsheet.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited
      this call sheet from being saved:
      </strong>
      <ul>
        <% @callsheet.errors.full_messages.each do |msg| %>
          <li><%= msg %></li>
        <% end %>
      </ul>
    </div>
  <% end %>

  <%= f.fields_for :crewmember do |crewmember| %>
    <fieldset>
      <%= crewmember.label :firstname, "First Name" %><br />
      <%= crewmember.text_field :firstname %>
    </fieldset>
  <% end %>

<% end %>
```

Comment: which field is blank ? can you insert a screen shot/image ?

Comment: The `<%= crewmember.text_field :firstname %>` field on the callsheet/new page is blank and there is only one listed.  ultimately I would like to insert the name of each crewmember and allow the user to remove crew members from the form.

Comment: did you try changing from <%= f.fields_for :crewmember do |crewmember| %>
to <%= f.fields_for :crewmembers do |crewmember| %>, please note the pluralization there.

Comment: when I do that nothing shows up at all

Comment: Is there 3 "@callsheet" records ? I mean the total count of "@callsheet" records....

Comment: in callsheet new method add this line `@crewmembers = @callsheet.crewmembers.build`

Answer (score 0):

You don't need `attr_accessible` (that's only for Rails 3).

You should also rename all your models to [`snake_case`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Snake_case), referencing with [`CamelCase`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CamelCase):

```
#app/models/call_sheet.rb
class CallSheet < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_many :cast_members
   has_many :crew_members
   accepts_nested_attributes_for :crew_members
end
```

As is the custom with `fields_for`, you also need to build the associated objects (if you're creating a `new` record) (you don't need to do this if `editing`):

```
#app/controllers/call_sheets_controller.rb
class CallSheetsController < ApplicationController
    before_action :set_departments

    def new
        @callsheet = Callsheet.new
        @callsheet.crew_members.build
    end

    def edit
        @callsheet = Callsheet.find params[:id]
    end

    def update
        @callsheet = Callsheet.find params[:id]
        @callsheet.update callsheet_params
    end

    private

    def set_departments
       @departments = Department.where(production_id: current_user.default_working_production_id)
    end

    def callsheet_params
       params.require(:callsheet).permit(crew_members_attributes: [:id, :firstname])
    end
end
```

This will allow you to use:

```
<%= form_for @callsheet do |f| %>
  <%= f.fields_for :crew_members do |crewmember| %>
      <%= crewmember.label :firstname, "First Name" %><br />
      <%= crewmember.text_field :firstname %>
  <% end %>
  <%= f.submit %>
<% end %>
```

--

When passing nested attributes through `fields_for`, you need several components:

- The correct association in your parent model
- An instantiated version of the associated model (`@parent.build_child`)
- Correct `fields_for` definition
- Passing correct `parameters` through your controller

I've outlined how to achieve the above, all of which you had incorrect.

---

You can also declare multiple validations in the same call:

```
#app/models/crew_member.rb
class CrewMember < ActiveRecord::Base
   validates :firstname, :email, presence: true
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Try changing

```
<%= f.fields_for :crewmember do |crewmember| %>
```

into

```
<%= f.fields_for :crewmember, @callsheet.crewmember || @callsheet.build_crewmember do |crewmember| %>
```